# Detecting pathways in a video using BoofCV on Android

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision, boofcv

For my application I have been looking into using BoofCV to detect if I am on a pathway or not.  The pathway is just gravel so it is the color of a standard roadway.  I'm not sure exactly what image processing technique to use.  The BoofCV demo app has a lot of features, but I would like to know which one is appropriate for what I'm trying to do.

Ultimately I'd like to have a toast appear on the screen when I am on a pathway.

Comment: so you want advice on how to process an image without providing the image? something you should fix :) and what do you mean with "detect if I am on a pathway or not" who are you? an autonomous car? a blind guy? I mean I know when I am on a pathway, I don't need a computer to show me a toast if I am.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I'm guessing that you' re using a regular camera, as real time input from a moving object. In that case you may need to:

1. Calibrate and Stabilize your input frames (**since your pathway is made from gravel**). BoofCV provides libraries.
2. Adjust exposure, contrast or brightness (for night/low light vision cameras or **low contrast frames**).
3. Use BoofCV's Binary Image Ops, according to your app's needs (**Image Thresholding**, Binary Labeling etc).
4. Use a classifier for 2 classes ("inside pathway", "outside pathway").
5. Process your output and feedback results to your "decision operator", to make a choice and guide your moving object.

**More details about your project may help for a better answer.**